# Universal ipa install never ends

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I have my device(ipad) registered in the devices developer center.
Until now I have use only iphone project in Deployment Info, but now I'm working on the ipad version using the sufix ~ipad and ~iphone on my xib files.

Then I change from only iphone project to universal project.
Everything works fine in Xcode but when I generate an .ipa file and try to install it via Itunes the install process never ends.

The weird thing if I back to only iphone project my ipa is installed without issues.

I'm using the last version of xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the wrong configuration.
I had try to generate and ipa file from an only iPad project. Then an error comes out.

I need add launch images for iPad sizes.

- Retina size 1536x2048
- Retina size 768x1028

Now I can generate and ipa file from an universal project.